# Facebook Request Dialog on Website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I saw  this:

http://demo.vatlab.net/RequestDialog.aspx

How they do this? Is the "Facebook Request Dialog" can be in a regular website, not canvas?

I'm looking for solution like this for a couple of days.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the dialog anywhere, but users will always be brought back to your canvas app (or mobile app) - if you don't have a canvas app (or mobile app) they won't see the requests

Comment: So I need to redirect them to facebook? I saw some where that this dialog can be use if the app enable request 2.0, what that mean?

Comment: That's referring to when the old requests system was retired and moved to the new system - if you want to use requests to bring users to the app, either implement a canvas app or a mobile app - either of which can receive requests - you can still send them from an off-facebook app / website

Comment: How can I do it on a Web site? When I try, although pop-up window appears but the requests are not sent. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Like i said, they are sent, but are hidden unless you have a canvas URL

Answer (score 0):

http://vatlab.com/asp-net-facebook-controls/request-dialog

This is their tutorial on the subject.

Comment: But this is a control of asp.net. I want to know how they do this in their website and no using canvas.